# General Theory for iOS cloud-backend event listening

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, backend, kinvey

The iOS app I'm developing is using a cloud backend (Kinvey to be specific), and I don't know how to approach the problem  of listening for certain changes in the backend that should signal updates to the UI. It's a multiplayer game I'm making, so for example, if somebody joins a match, I would want all the other players in that same match to know that a new player has joined, etcetera.

If you could offer me the general theory on how to approach this kind of task, as well as some pointers on how to begin coding the proper functions (global functions?), I'd really appreciate it. I'm using swift by the way.

Comment: If you were using cloudKit than you could use subscriptions, unsure if Kinvey provide this, although I suspect they do.

Answer (score -1):

Apple Push notifications are a good mechanism for this. Push notifications are initiated from the Kinvey backend, based on certain triggers you can code in your Business Logic layer. E.g. "joining a match" will most likely trigger some type of update to a Kinvey collection. You can then add a BL hook that sends the push notification. The notifications arrives in the app programmatically, and you then can handle from an AppDelegate handler.

Example business logic that hooks into an update/save request in order to notify other users (very similar to your use-case):
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/business-logic#Triggeringpushnotifications

Overview on how to set up push in the backend and in your app:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/push

Comment: When I think of push notifications I think of those pop-up notifications some apps give you, but I can use this technology to initiate any number of UI changes such as changing an image or doing a segue?

Comment: Yes you can, by using silent push which just invokes the handler and doesn't pop up an alert. Set "content-available: 1" and set the correct background modes in developer.apple.com.  See http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/reference/business-logic/reference.html#Payloads

Comment: According to the App Store Review Guidelines, "apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected", so I don't think this will work.